# Multiple VM Templates vs Service Templates

Tags: system-center

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the need/usage of a Service Template in System Center 2012 R2. I understand that when you define a service, you are specifying one or more vm templates that will be deployed.

In my case, I need to set up VM's for use in online virtual courses that will be accessed via RDP. Each course definition will include 2 or more VM's (domain controller, file server, web server, etc). And for each student that registers, one "set" of vm's will be stood up.

Is a Service Template the correct choice here? My thinking is that I define VM templates for each type of server (DC, web, file, etc), and then define a Service Template for each course (course 101 may be 2-tier whereas course 201 may be a 3-tier), and then create an instance of a given Service Template for each student.

Or is the more proper approach to just create instances of VM templates as needed?